# Retrofit Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Sorry for my bad English

I have a web service that delivers in the following format in json, I want to consume it from my android app using retrofit.

```
{"datos":
[{"codigo_centro":"Plantacion","descripcion_articulo":"Banano", "categoria_centro":"Admin"}, 
{"codigo_centro":"Finca","descripcion_articulo":"Finca ","categoria_centro":"Admin"},
{"codigo_centro":"Pante","descripcion_articulo":"Pante","categoria_centro":"Admin"}
],"error":false}
```

This is my apiservice

```
@GET("obtener_centro.php")
Call<CentroResponse> getDatos();
```

Response

```
@SerializedName("datos")
private ArrayList<Centro> datos;
private boolean Error;
```

Callback

```
    class CentroCallBack implements Callback<CentroResponse> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<CentroResponse> call, Response<CentroResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            CentroResponse centroResponse = response.body();
            if(!centroResponse.isError()) {
                if(centroResponse.getDatos()!=null){
//                        poblarSpinnerCentro(centroResponse.getDatos());
                }
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(reporteActivity.this, "Ha Ocurrido un Error en el Formato de Respuesta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<CentroResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(reporteActivity.this, "Fallo la conexion a Internet: "+call.request().url()+" "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void obtenerCentros() {
    try{
        Call<CentroResponse> call = OPCApiAdapter.getApiService().getDatos();
        call.enqueue(new CentroCallBack());
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

when I try to go through my arrayList  all the data is null

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

this is the answer I receive in logcat

```
    11-02 18:23:19.339 25501-25849/com.fgtit D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    11-02 18:23:19.339 25501-25849/com.fgtit D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
    11-02 18:23:19.352 25501-25849/com.fgtit D/OkHttp: {"datos":
    [{"codigo_centro":"Plantacion","descripcion_articulo":"Banano", "categoria_centro":"Admin"}, 
    {"codigo_centro":"Finca","descripcion_articulo":"Finca ","categoria_centro":"Admin"},
    {"codigo_centro":"Pante","descripcion_articulo":"Pante","categoria_centro":"Admin"}
    ],"error":false} 11-02 18:23:19.353 25501-25849/com.fgtit D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (31547-byte body)
    11-02 18:23:19.518 25501-25501/com.fgtit V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{3430af23 token=android.os.BinderProxy@26296c20 {com.fgtit/report.activity.activityMenu}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@1f2d0d4c
```

Comment: Can you able to send the code snippet for the "Centro" class? Which you are using inside the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must check if your app reaches your API. To do so, you can drop a breakpoint on the `if (response.isSuccessful()) {` line, and another one on `Toast.makeText` line. Then debug your project, so you'll see your API response.

After that, check if the response is successful, if so, check your `response.body`. if all looks good, please, print your response body and place here.